# Pacemaker High availability on dynamic NFS client mount point

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to setup a Redhat cluster with N + 1 (N=active server) which has a standby server for HA.

Each active server will have the same application path mounted on NFS.
For example :
NFS server has example exportfs below:

```
 /mnt/application1/ server1.example.com(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
 /mnt/application2/ server2.example.com(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Each of the active Server will mount each as example below:

```
Server 1 : mount 192.168.10.15:/mnt/application1/ /application/
Server 2 : mount 192.168.10.15:/mnt/application2/ /application/
```

The File system resource was created using :

```
pcs resource create fs_app1 ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem device="/mnt/application1/" directory="/application" options="bind" fstype="none" --group app1
```

The failover successful if the standby server in pre-mounted on the NFS mountpoint.

But I would need to have a dynamic mounting on the standby server, which it won't have any pre-mounted NFS mountpoint, and if Server 1 failover, the mounting on standby server will be taking mount 192.168.10.15:/mnt/application1/ from NFS.

At the moment I will get this error if the mountpoint is not pre-mounted.

```
* fs_app1_start_0 on server1.example.com 'unknown error' (1): call=155, status=complete, exitreason='Couldn't mount filesystem /mnt/application1 on /application1/',
    last-rc-change='Thu Apr 11 06:38:56 2019', queued=0ms, exec=84ms
```

Is there a way to achieve dynamic nfs mounting using pacemaker resource?

Comment: Further looking into Filesystem source, the command should be 
pcs resource create fs_app1 ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem device="192.168.10.15:/mnt/application1/" directory="/application" fstype="nfs4" --group app1

and it worked.